# Insert data from database into textbox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm not sure if there is a way of doing this or not. I am trying to enable users of a site to edit the reviews they have entered. My lecturer won't let us use the enable editing option available in the grid view task pane and I am struggling to find a solution. I know how to write the content contents of a database to a dropdown list. But I am getting errors when doing it for a text box. What I am trying to do is get the user to select the name of the movie they wrote the review for, generate the content they wrote for that review and insert it into a text box so that it can be edited. Is this a simple thing to do? Or will I need to think of something else?

The code I used for the dropdown list is:

```
ddlRemoveUreview.DataSource = aDataReader
ddlRemoveUreview.DataTextField = "MovieTitle"
ddlRemoveUreview.DataValueField = "MovieTitle"
ddlRemoveUreview.DataBind()
```

Code that I have written to write the content to a text box:

```
query = "Select ReviewText FROM MReviewTexts, Movies, UserDetails WHERE MReviewTexts.MReviewID = Movies.MReviewID AND Movies.UserID = UserDetails.UserID AND UserDetails.Username = '" & HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name & "'"
Dim cmd = New OleDbCommand(query, dbConnect)
    aDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    If aDataReader.Read() = True Then
        'A row was returned
        txtContent.Text = aDataReader(0)
    Else
        txtContent.Text = "No content entered - please edit"
    End If
```

Got it working. My sql was wrong - correct solution is:

```
Dim query As String = "Select ReviewText FROM MReviewTexts, MovieReviews, UserDetails WHERE MReviewTexts.MReviewID = MovieReviews.MReviewID AND MovieReviews.UserID = UserDetails.UserID AND UserDetails.Username = '" & HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name & "'"
    dbConnect.Open()
    Dim cmd = New OleDbCommand(query, dbConnect)
    aDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    If aDataReader.Read() = True Then
        'A row was returned
        txtContent.Text = Convert.ToString(aDataReader(0))
    Else
        txtContent.Text = "No content entered - please edit"
    End If
```

Comment: It's a website that was given as an assignment. I have researched it for hours and said tutor is not very forthcoming with information on how to do stuff

Comment: @user1850189 You didn't post the relevant piece of code to your problem. Please post the rest of it.

Comment: @TLS - Please don't tag with homework, it's obsolete and being removed.

Comment: You should post the solution to your question as an answer, irrespective of whether the question gets removed.

Comment: @Mike - good call.  Here's the link to Meta talking about why it's going away:  [The homework tag is now officially deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147100)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works. It displays the content from the database into a textbox:

```
Dim query As String = "Select ReviewText FROM MReviewTexts, MovieReviews, UserDetails WHERE MReviewTexts.MReviewID = MovieReviews.MReviewID AND MovieReviews.UserID = UserDetails.UserID AND UserDetails.Username = '" & HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name & "'"
dbConnect.Open()
Dim cmd = New OleDbCommand(query, dbConnect)
aDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
If aDataReader.Read() = True Then
    'A row was returned
    txtContent.Text = Convert.ToString(aDataReader(0))
Else
    txtContent.Text = "No content entered - please edit"
End If
```